# Error at installing Caffe in Ubuntu 17.04 (libhdf5.so)

Tags: python, opencv, caffe, opencv3.0, ubuntu-17.04

Durring installation (compiling) Caffe (the first version) on my Ubuntu 17.04, I receive the following error:

> *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"libhdf5.so"', needed by 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0'. Stop.

[image]

My computer specification is as following:

```
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

The used gcc:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/g++-4.9   10        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   10        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gcc-5     10        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/gcc-6     10        manual mode
```

OpenCV version:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.2.0
```

`CUDNN` version is the latest what is `v6.0`.

I already added the following regarding [the official website](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's^"hdf5.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5.h"^g' -e 's^"hdf5_hl.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.h"^g' '{}' \;

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0 libhdf5.so

sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2 libhdf5_hl.so
```

and modified the `Makefile.config` as:

```
 USE_CUDNN := 1
 OPENCV_VERSION := 3
 CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda-8.0
 BLAS := atlas
 PYTHON_INCLUDE :=  /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
 INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
 LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

and `Makefile` as:

```
NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)

LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy \
  lmdb boost_system boost_filesystem hdf5_hl hdf5 m \
  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs opencv_videoio
```

But still get the same error after running either `cmake` .. or `make all -j8` or `make pycaffe -j4`:

> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:267: recipe for target
>   'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed make[2](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide): ***
>   [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1129: recipe for target
>   'python/CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir/rule' failed make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/047Yw.png): ***
>   [python/CMakeFiles/pycaffe.dir/rule] Error 2
>
> Makefile:487: recipe for target 'pycaffe' failed make: *** [pycaffe]
>   Error 2

Here are the list of related packages after executing:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then:

```
$ ls -l | grep hdf5
```

The result are as bellow:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      4096 May 17 06:37 hdf5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    972640 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        22 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_cpp.so -> libhdf5_cpp.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        22 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_cpp.so.100 -> libhdf5_cpp.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    414392 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_cpp.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     13098 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_hl_cpp.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100 -> libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     14736 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        27 May 21 16:18 libhdf5_hl.so -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   7841328 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    398780 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        33 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        33 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    254920 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    245528 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_hl.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    186570 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        35 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        35 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100 -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    121464 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_hl.so -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    142744 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      4084 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial.settings
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial.so -> libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3491952 Dec  5 08:27 libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        24 May 21 16:16 libhdf5.so -> libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am struggling with isntalling Caffe at last few days. Also, I considered installing [Caffe2](https://caffe2.ai/), But I could not install that one, well.

Comment: i think you ve done all the fixes that i could think of.... but for me,i had a previous problem that i had a missing a header file of hd5,it got away when in updated my include dir to INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/ then this where i got the same problem as  you and this same fix of renaming symbolic links worked for me

Comment: and you  should always do  make clean before another build(after applying the symlink fix) ideally you should always delete the build folder and start again

Comment: Yes, I already did that. But, still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a generic build hint, make sure you run 'make all' before 'make pycaffe'.
2. The official website confirms the installation only on Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.10 at this date (May 23rd,2017).
3. Make sure you have CUDNN version 5.1 (not the latest 6) as it is the only version that is recommended (23 May 2017).

Comment: I install the Ubuntu 16.X (rather than 17.0X) and also CUDNN 5.1 rather the latest version v6.0. So, it works pretty well now.

Answer (score 0):

The two following line are not always necessary and may even cause issues:

`sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.10.1.0 libhdf5.so
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.10.0.2 libhdf5_hl.so`

Besides, make sure all the `hdf5` dependencies are already installed.

Comment: As it shows also in the question, I already did that. Thanks though Amir.

Answer (score 0):

used fallowing command 
`sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip` or `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip`
and
`sudo -H apt-get install python-tk` or `sudo -H apt-get install python3-tk`
and
`sudo -H pip3 install easysetup` or `sudo -H pip2 install easysetup`

then start again.

Comment: I did exactly, but the issue was still there. Thanks though.